# Regex to match anything what another regex doesn't match

Tags: c#, regex

I'm firm using regex. I've the following regex that matches all I want:

[`#(?<nonCapturing>\?\:)?(?:\(\?(?![\)])(?<addOpt>[ar]*)(?:\-(?<remOpt>[ar]+))?\))?\b(?<id>\w+)\b(?:\[\]|(?:(?=\[)(?:[^\[\]]|(?<open>\[)|(?<subFormat-open>\]))+?(?(open)(?!))))?`](http://goo.gl/bkKm9E)

Very long - sorry. It is used to parse a format string for arbitrary objects. It enables me to specify a property (e.g. IntValue) and forward an optional child format to it.

It matches a `#` followed by an optional non capturing pattern `?:`, followed by an optional 'options' pattern `(?r)` or `(?a-r)`. Then the property name followed by a pair of `[]`.

For the following input:

`Int: #IntValue Bool: #BoolValue[]Word Str: '#StrValue' Double: #DoubleValue[#.00] #(?r)Bar[#(?r)StrValue[#Length]]`

it matches:

- #IntValue
- #BoolValue[]
- #StrValue
- #DoubleValue[#.00]
- #(?r)Bar[#(?r)StrValue[#Length]]

Fine.

But now I need all the other stuff. I want it in the same regex to be able to foreach over all matches (I can decide whitch case I have by checking whether `id` or `plain` has a capture).

The default pattern to do that is: `((?!<regex that matches what you want>).)*`

In my case that will look like (Pattern: `<REG>|(?<plain>(?:(?!<REG>).)+)`)
what resuls in that huge regex (whitch maches perfectly):

[`(?:#(?<nonCapturing>\?\:)?(?:\(\?(?![\)])(?<addOpt>[ar]*)(?:\-(?<remOpt>[ar]+))?\))?\b(?<id>\w+)\b(?:\[\]|(?:(?=\[)(?:[^\[\]]|(?<open>\[)|(?<subFormat-open>\]))+?(?(open)(?!))))?)|(?<plain>(?:(?!(?:#(?<nonCapturing>\?\:)?(?:\(\?(?![\)])(?<addOpt>[ar]*)(?:\-(?<remOpt>[ar]+))?\))?\b(?<id>\w+)\b(?:\[\]|(?:(?=\[)(?:[^\[\]]|(?<open>\[)|(?<subFormat-open>\]))+?(?(open)(?!))))?)|(?<plain>(?:(#(?<nonCapturing>\?\:)?(?:\(\?(?![\)])(?<addOpt>[ar]*)(?:\-(?<remOpt>[ar]+))?\))?\b(?<id>\w+)\b(?:\[\]|(?:(?=\[)(?:[^\[\]]|(?<open>\[)|(?<subFormat-open>\]))+?(?(open)(?!))))?).)+)).)+)`](http://goo.gl/Ot09LQ)

Puh. It does what it should but...

Is there any other way to match all that's not matched by a previous regex part?

Is that clear?

Comment: Why not just do `!regex.IsMatch(input);`?

Comment: It looks like there is no way, unless you want to try PCRE.net, where you could make use of PCRE `(*SKIP)(*F)` verbs. Still, it will be a long regex. Perhaps, you can match the first type of substrings, and then split using them to get the rest?

Comment: @Rob because I parse a string. I need all parts. Some parts matches my property pattern. But now I need also all the other stuff. `Regex.IsMatch` will only check whether there is a match or not. YES there are multiple matches. The whole string will be matched. `regex.IsMatch` will not help me.

Comment: @Rob, and get `false`? Do you think he wants bool in result or text that is not matched? Vera, and what about deleting all that is matched?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri To be honest, it wasn't clear from the question (to me). That's why I added a comment, not an answer. Though his reply comment clears it up.

Comment: Wouldn't appending a `|[^#]+` to the pattern be an acceptable solution?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski ??? WOW!!! It seems to work. It looks so simple. I've to think about it to understand WHY it works (to be sure that it works for all cases).

Comment: Well... your objects all start with `#`, so `[^#]+` will simply capture everything else. This assumes that an `#` is *always* the start of an object you want to match specifically.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Grrr.. You posted your comment during I was writing my comment. I think I got it. Yes I think you're right. (I want everything.) But my property pattern does always start with `#`. That forces the alternation to use the other case. Because of the greedyness of a regex this should work. Please post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're lucky: your regex starts with an anchor character, which is `#`. We can take advantage of that.

Add an alternative to the pattern: `|[^#]+`. This will consume everything but `#` characters, leaving the special cases starting with `#` to the first part of the pattern. A `#` character will therefore always start a new match.

There's still a minor catch: you have a non-optional `id` group surrounded by two `\b` anchors in that first part, which means if you have a `#` in the input string which is not followed by a letter (let's say something like `foo#!bar`), that `#` won't be matched by the second part of the pattern either.

A simple solution to this problem is to use `|[^#]+|#` at the end of the pattern to account for this edge case. That third `#` case will be matched only if the first case fails.

Comment: _Everything after that is optional._ No. The `id` is not optional but Your explanation works either.

Comment: Oh right, I must have seen a `?` which is not there